# CRUD nodejs/express server: app.put req.body is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I just wrote a ultrasimple nodejs backend with basic crud operations. However on the put statement i don't receive  the body of my request:

```
 app.put('/note-update/:id', function (req, res) {
  var noteId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body)
  db.collection('notes').update({
    _id: noteId
  }, req.body, (err, result) => {
    res.send(
      (err === null) ? {
        msg: req.body
      } : {
        msg: err
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Here is the call i execute with ajax:

```
var note = {
    _id: "599e660cbc845b4e2952715f",
    name: "Genauer Detailbeschrieb",
    note: "Ey-10"
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/note-update/599e660cbc845b4e2952715f',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(note)
})
```

as you can see i have a console.log(req.body) and all i get is {}

Comment: Did you use the `bodyParser` middleware for express ?

Comment: Is your **post** Http method working? If not use **BodyParser** middleware

Comment: yeah post is working with bodyParser although i never tried with ajax

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan just checkt the post.. its req.body is also empty

Comment: Did u add `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan oh.. woooow thanks alot .. i just had `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))` included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the bodyparser?

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Plz show more code for your node setup if it doesn't work.