# Webhook Gitlab on push events - Empty request body?

Tags: node.js, gitlab

I'm trying to use gitlab webhooks for push events. I successfully reached my nodejs app when pushing files to my repo, but for some reasons, my request body seems empty.

Even with a very basic code, I cannot receive my push information (author, message, etc.) :

```
app.post('/myurl', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('req.body = ');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).end();
}
```

The result is always :

```
req.body = 
{}
```

Does anyone know why my request body is empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, putting the answer here for people.

I wasn't using a json bodyparser. Thanks to, [sandrooco in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857143/crud-nodejs-express-server-app-put-req-body-is-empty), I figured out that I just needed to add in my app :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Sorry for being a noob in nodejs.